# Custom Animations on Windows Phone 8.1 RT

Tags: animation, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I'm trying to do a sliding animation that the user can interact with.

Its basically a slider that the user can drag across the screen.

I currently implemented it with a pointer-moved event and it works simply updating the sliders position to the current drag point. But the animation is crude and the dragging experience have the wrong feel.

I would like to implement my own custom animation giving the slider mass and acceleration. But I can't figure out how to implement it on Windows Phone 8.1 RT.

There do not appear to be any kind of update/render loop that i can hook into on the UI thread to get a steady update frequency.

Is there some other way to get what I want?

`DoubleAnimation` do not seem to work since it have fixed start and end times.
Event though the `TimeLine` classes enabled continues animations there don't seem to be a way to hook into them other then faking a dependency property and binding a double to that.

I could create my own thread and then marshal to the UI thread but that seems wrong.

EDIT:

Clarification. Im not trying to implement an actual Slider control. But my own custom control. Imagin a coin on a table you can drag around with your finger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the inbuilt [SmallChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.rangebase.smallchange)
and [LargeChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.rangebase.largechange) properties of the slider would achieve the interaction you are looking for.

Also have a look at the [StepFrequency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.slider.stepfrequency.aspx) property which depends on SnapsTo property of the slider.

Comment: Im not using the `Slider` control. Im trying to implement my own custom control.

Comment: You should be working with gestures using the GesureRecogniser API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer.aspx)

Comment: Gestures just seem to be able to recognize a certain gesture and let you hook up on it. I need something that will give me a steady stream of events that will let me perform an animation.

Comment: "coin on a table you can drag around with your finger" pretty much resembles a gesture scenario for me :/  and aslo PointerMoved, PointerReleased, PointerPressed,PointerCanceled these events happen in your scenario consider the coin as a point.

Comment: True, but when i release the finger, PointerReleased i want the coint to continue moving for a while as it deaccelerates. But the problem is i no longer recieve PointerMoved events.

Comment: Getting an idea of your scenario now, so all you have to do is accumulate data on pointer manipulation(direction,speed etc.) and on pointer released translate the position of the coin depending on the data you had accumulated in the pointer manipulation event.

Comment: That is correct. But i need a way to update the coin while it still has velocity. But where? I have no update/render loop to hook into. And the events stop after the PointerReleased.

Comment: check manipulationdelta, i hope you are looking for that (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationdelta(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: I ended up working with GestureRecognizer since it allows for inertia and updates after the control is released.

Comment: Glad that I could help. If possible document it, so that someone else can use it. :)